# How run jboss-cli on start docker container with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, jboss, containers, dockerfile, wildfly

I am trying create image docker container with Dockerfile. I need execute some commands with jboss-cli when docker container starts. To execute jboss-cli it is necessary that the wildfly service is running.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:latest

USER jboss

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin --silent

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And i tried add a jboss-cli command in my Dockerfile

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:latest

USER jboss

COPY mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar /opt/jboss/

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin --silent

USER root
#in this line is needed to change owner file to jboss user use this file
RUN chown jboss.root /opt/jboss/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar
USER jboss

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh", "-c", "controller=localhost:9990", "--user=admin", "--password=admin", "--command=\"module add --name=com.mysql --resources=/opt/jboss/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api\""]
```

when i run the docker run command:

```
docker run --name=wildfly-ci -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 wildfly-ci
```

i receive this message error from jboss-cli when run docker command

```
Failed to connect to the controller: The controller is not available at localhost:9990: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9990. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9990. The connection failed: XNIO000812: Connection closed unexpectedly
```

I don't know if is because the wildfly's service is not running yet in this moment or because is a some behavior with Docker Container.

Comment: when i run the docker exec CONTAINER_ID jboss-cli commands..

The command run with success

Comment: The 'module add' command is available without needing to provide the '-c' argument to jboss-cli. So you could add it as another RUN directive in your Dockerfile.

Comment: but i need add module, driver and datasource but I did not want create a image in docker hub with steps ready

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @ОлегГаврилів no, i make sh(linux) e cmd(windows) script to run this.

Comment: @WeltonLeãoMachado, could you show scripts?

Comment: From docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd): **There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.**

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
   RUN /bin/sh -c '$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -c=standalone-full.xml &' && \
      sleep 10 && \
      cd /tmp && \
      $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="module add --name=org.postgresql --resources=$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/postgresql-42.2.5.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api,javax.servlet.api" && \
      $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:shutdown 


    # User root to modify war owners
    USER root

    CMD ["/opt/eap/bin/standalone.sh", "-c", "standalone-full.xml", "-b", "0.0.0.0","-bmanagement","0.0.0.0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Dockerfile with single CMD,

Dockerfile

FROM jboss/wildfly:latest

USER jboss

COPY mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar /opt/jboss/

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin --silent

USER root
RUN chown jboss.root /opt/jboss/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar
USER jboss

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0",";","/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh", "-c", "controller=localhost:9990", "--user=admin", "--password=admin", "--command=\"module add --name=com.mysql --resources=/opt/jboss/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api\""]

Comment: For what you are trying to do, it might be simpler to just use docker to apply a patch to the xml file, rather than trying to use the jboss-cli